# NSOperationCount shows improper number

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I can't understand why my operation count in queue is so strange. I have a queue, where I add operations. When it is added I print `add:` and requests hash. Then I have processingBlock happening in dispatch
`AFNetworking` - `AFImageRequestOperation` - `imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageProcessingBlock:success:failure:`.

When `imageProcessingBlock` is starting I print `process, hash`,

on `success` block I print `done, hash`

and `failure` block - `fail, hash`.

I'm also printing count of the queue `queue.operationCount` as `op1=` just before calling cancel on one operation `if (![operation isExecuting]) [operation cancel]`. It can happen, that the operation is nil (already finished or doesn't exist), so seeing `op1=` doesn't mean that previous operation is in fact cancelled. If it would, we wouldnt see `process` and `done/fail` logs, while we can see it.

My queue has `queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;` property set.

Log:

```
2014-03-05 13:14:06.800 app[7149:60b] add: 2889023970
2014-03-05 13:14:07.099 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:07.102 app[7149:60b] add: 2889023970
2014-03-05 13:14:07.267 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:07.271 app[7149:60b] add: 702670786
2014-03-05 13:14:07.431 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:07.435 app[7149:60b] add: 291730858
2014-03-05 13:14:07.601 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:07.603 app[7149:60b] add: 151251145
2014-03-05 13:14:07.703 app[7149:3903] process, 2889023970
2014-03-05 13:14:07.798 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:07.800 app[7149:60b] add: 3495583422
2014-03-05 13:14:07.982 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:07.984 app[7149:60b] add: 3951083409
2014-03-05 13:14:08.183 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:08.185 app[7149:60b] add: 3097363895
2014-03-05 13:14:08.366 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:08.369 app[7149:60b] add: 3940561568
2014-03-05 13:14:08.565 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:08.568 app[7149:60b] add: 3549899699
2014-03-05 13:14:08.703 app[7149:1603] process, 2889023970
2014-03-05 13:14:08.717 app[7149:60b] done, 2889023970
2014-03-05 13:14:08.720 app[7149:3903] process, 702670786
2014-03-05 13:14:08.764 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:08.767 app[7149:60b] add: 2257512580
2014-03-05 13:14:08.932 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:08.934 app[7149:60b] add: 1269923969
2014-03-05 13:14:09.099 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:09.101 app[7149:60b] add: 1717452702
2014-03-05 13:14:09.264 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:09.266 app[7149:60b] add: 3204563151
2014-03-05 13:14:09.448 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:09.450 app[7149:60b] add: 914226193
2014-03-05 13:14:09.648 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:09.649 app[7149:60b] add: 4288960663
2014-03-05 13:14:09.864 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:09.868 app[7149:60b] add: 1010721546
2014-03-05 13:14:09.908 app[7149:60b] done, 2889023970
2014-03-05 13:14:10.081 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:10.083 app[7149:60b] add: 1346065135
2014-03-05 13:14:10.298 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:10.301 app[7149:60b] add: 1610846086
2014-03-05 13:14:10.413 app[7149:60b] done, 702670786
2014-03-05 13:14:10.531 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:10.534 app[7149:60b] add: 1279065803
2014-03-05 13:14:10.748 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:10.749 app[7149:60b] add: 56514476
2014-03-05 13:14:10.949 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:10.951 app[7149:60b] add: 1647541451
2014-03-05 13:14:11.132 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:11.134 app[7149:60b] add: 1464536901
2014-03-05 13:14:11.297 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:11.300 app[7149:60b] add: 3032567003
2014-03-05 13:14:11.464 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:11.466 app[7149:60b] add: 1916037766
2014-03-05 13:14:11.535 app[7149:3903] process, 291730858
2014-03-05 13:14:11.648 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:11.650 app[7149:60b] add: 3051826257
2014-03-05 13:14:11.848 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:11.850 app[7149:60b] add: 3076241399
2014-03-05 13:14:11.907 app[7149:1603] process, 151251145
2014-03-05 13:14:11.952 app[7149:3c03] process, 3495583422
2014-03-05 13:14:12.098 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:12.100 app[7149:60b] add: 48397485
2014-03-05 13:14:12.331 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:12.334 app[7149:60b] add: 3887034591
2014-03-05 13:14:12.548 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:12.551 app[7149:60b] add: 898950083
2014-03-05 13:14:12.711 app[7149:7b27] process, 3951083409
2014-03-05 13:14:12.734 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:12.737 app[7149:60b] add: 3912316789
2014-03-05 13:14:12.931 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:12.935 app[7149:60b] add: 1407228822
2014-03-05 13:14:13.131 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:13.135 app[7149:60b] add: 3336394733
2014-03-05 13:14:13.331 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:13.335 app[7149:60b] add: 590013065
2014-03-05 13:14:13.550 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:13.553 app[7149:60b] add: 1365020375
2014-03-05 13:14:13.765 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:13.768 app[7149:60b] add: 3533463993
2014-03-05 13:14:13.788 app[7149:60b] done, 291730858
2014-03-05 13:14:14.014 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:14.018 app[7149:60b] add: 3276861409
2014-03-05 13:14:14.231 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:14.233 app[7149:60b] add: 110569377
2014-03-05 13:14:14.438 app[7149:60b] done, 151251145
2014-03-05 13:14:14.448 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:14.451 app[7149:60b] add: 3082863482
2014-03-05 13:14:14.507 app[7149:60b] done, 3495583422
2014-03-05 13:14:14.664 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:14.667 app[7149:60b] add: 2880825480
2014-03-05 13:14:14.881 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:14.885 app[7149:60b] add: 174982724
2014-03-05 13:14:15.081 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:15.084 app[7149:60b] add: 3595970015
2014-03-05 13:14:15.130 app[7149:60b] done, 3951083409
2014-03-05 13:14:15.432 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:15.450 app[7149:60b] add: 2167277765
2014-03-05 13:14:15.698 app[7149:1603] process, 3940561568
2014-03-05 13:14:15.731 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:15.735 app[7149:60b] add: 1556977129
2014-03-05 13:14:16.018 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:16.021 app[7149:60b] add: 2295161098
2014-03-05 13:14:16.265 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:16.268 app[7149:60b] add: 3293570222
2014-03-05 13:14:16.465 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:16.468 app[7149:60b] add: 1495040366
2014-03-05 13:14:16.648 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:16.650 app[7149:60b] add: 2960130674
2014-03-05 13:14:16.848 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:16.850 app[7149:60b] add: 2192695544
2014-03-05 13:14:17.031 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:17.034 app[7149:60b] add: 875349923
2014-03-05 13:14:17.248 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:17.250 app[7149:60b] add: 550530235
2014-03-05 13:14:17.498 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:17.501 app[7149:60b] add: 3315589548
2014-03-05 13:14:17.588 app[7149:60b] done, 3940561568
2014-03-05 13:14:17.591 app[7149:1603] process, 3097363895
2014-03-05 13:14:17.731 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:17.733 app[7149:60b] add: 3276473474
2014-03-05 13:14:17.981 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:17.984 app[7149:60b] add: 1965226584
2014-03-05 13:14:18.215 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:18.217 app[7149:60b] add: 2261494312
2014-03-05 13:14:18.431 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:18.433 app[7149:60b] add: 683653812
2014-03-05 13:14:18.631 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:18.634 app[7149:60b] add: 959046345
2014-03-05 13:14:18.864 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:18.867 app[7149:60b] add: 3287457211
2014-03-05 13:14:19.081 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:19.084 app[7149:60b] add: 406162445
2014-03-05 13:14:19.245 app[7149:4e0b] process, 3549899699
2014-03-05 13:14:19.331 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:19.333 app[7149:60b] add: 3959798522
2014-03-05 13:14:19.342 app[7149:3c03] process, 2257512580
2014-03-05 13:14:19.459 app[7149:7b27] process, 1717452702
2014-03-05 13:14:19.547 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:19.549 app[7149:60b] add: 4189223064
2014-03-05 13:14:19.765 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:19.769 app[7149:60b] add: 3605790954
2014-03-05 13:14:19.964 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:19.966 app[7149:60b] add: 2927423940
2014-03-05 13:14:20.008 app[7149:60b] done, 3097363895
2014-03-05 13:14:20.011 app[7149:1603] process, 1269923969
2014-03-05 13:14:20.228 app[7149:3903] process, 3204563151
2014-03-05 13:14:20.312 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:21.050 app[7149:60b] Received memory warning.
2014-03-05 13:14:21.207 app[7149:862b] process, 914226193
2014-03-05 13:14:21.650 app[7149:7d0b] process, 4288960663
2014-03-05 13:14:21.707 app[7149:60b] add: 3605790954
2014-03-05 13:14:21.717 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:21.723 app[7149:60b] add: 3605790954
2014-03-05 13:14:21.731 app[7149:60b] op1=2
2014-03-05 13:14:21.740 app[7149:60b] add: 3605790954
2014-03-05 13:14:21.749 app[7149:60b] op1=3
2014-03-05 13:14:21.759 app[7149:60b] add: 3605790954
2014-03-05 13:14:21.764 app[7149:60b] op1=4
2014-03-05 13:14:21.780 app[7149:60b] add: 3605790954
2014-03-05 13:14:22.198 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:22.200 app[7149:60b] add: 4189223064
2014-03-05 13:14:22.415 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:22.417 app[7149:60b] add: 3959798522
2014-03-05 13:14:22.420 app[7149:60b] done, 1717452702
2014-03-05 13:14:22.422 app[7149:7b27] process, 1010721546
2014-03-05 13:14:22.648 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:22.650 app[7149:60b] add: 406162445
2014-03-05 13:14:22.768 app[7149:60b] done, 3549899699
2014-03-05 13:14:22.784 app[7149:60b] done, 2257512580
2014-03-05 13:14:22.787 app[7149:3c03] process, 1346065135
2014-03-05 13:14:22.898 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:22.900 app[7149:60b] add: 3287457211
2014-03-05 13:14:23.115 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:23.120 app[7149:60b] add: 959046345
2014-03-05 13:14:23.331 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:23.333 app[7149:60b] add: 683653812
2014-03-05 13:14:23.499 app[7149:60b] done, 1269923969
2014-03-05 13:14:23.531 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:23.535 app[7149:60b] add: 2261494312
2014-03-05 13:14:23.749 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:23.752 app[7149:60b] add: 1965226584
2014-03-05 13:14:23.799 app[7149:60b] done, 3204563151
2014-03-05 13:14:23.966 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:23.968 app[7149:60b] add: 3276473474
2014-03-05 13:14:24.198 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:24.202 app[7149:60b] add: 3315589548
2014-03-05 13:14:24.267 app[7149:60b] done, 914226193
2014-03-05 13:14:24.270 app[7149:862b] process, 1610846086
2014-03-05 13:14:24.415 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:24.417 app[7149:60b] add: 550530235
2014-03-05 13:14:24.631 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:24.635 app[7149:60b] add: 875349923
2014-03-05 13:14:24.848 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:24.851 app[7149:60b] add: 2192695544
2014-03-05 13:14:25.031 app[7149:60b] done, 4288960663
2014-03-05 13:14:25.031 app[7149:7d0b] process, 1279065803
2014-03-05 13:14:25.099 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:25.101 app[7149:60b] add: 2960130674
2014-03-05 13:14:25.320 app[7149:4e0b] process, 56514476
2014-03-05 13:14:25.367 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:25.370 app[7149:60b] add: 1495040366
2014-03-05 13:14:25.600 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:25.602 app[7149:60b] add: 3293570222
2014-03-05 13:14:25.783 app[7149:60b] done, 1010721546
2014-03-05 13:14:25.815 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:25.818 app[7149:60b] add: 2295161098
2014-03-05 13:14:26.065 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:26.069 app[7149:60b] add: 1556977129
2014-03-05 13:14:26.243 app[7149:60b] done, 1346065135
2014-03-05 13:14:26.298 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:26.302 app[7149:60b] add: 2167277765
2014-03-05 13:14:26.548 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:26.552 app[7149:60b] add: 3595970015
2014-03-05 13:14:26.782 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:26.785 app[7149:60b] add: 174982724
2014-03-05 13:14:27.148 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:27.188 app[7149:60b] add: 2880825480
2014-03-05 13:14:27.448 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:27.451 app[7149:60b] add: 3082863482
2014-03-05 13:14:27.558 app[7149:60b] done, 1610846086
2014-03-05 13:14:27.631 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:27.633 app[7149:60b] add: 110569377
2014-03-05 13:14:27.805 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:27.811 app[7149:60b] add: 3276861409
2014-03-05 13:14:27.969 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:27.974 app[7149:60b] add: 3533463993
2014-03-05 13:14:28.101 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:28.111 app[7149:60b] add: 1365020375
2014-03-05 13:14:28.249 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:28.254 app[7149:60b] add: 590013065
2014-03-05 13:14:28.400 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:28.403 app[7149:60b] add: 3336394733
2014-03-05 13:14:28.518 app[7149:60b] Received memory warning.
2014-03-05 13:14:28.532 app[7149:3c03] process, 1647541451
2014-03-05 13:14:28.632 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:28.637 app[7149:60b] add: 1407228822
2014-03-05 13:14:28.704 app[7149:60b] done, 1279065803
2014-03-05 13:14:28.716 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:28.720 app[7149:60b] add: 3912316789
2014-03-05 13:14:28.884 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:28.889 app[7149:60b] add: 898950083
2014-03-05 13:14:29.023 app[7149:60b] done, 56514476
2014-03-05 13:14:29.068 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:29.074 app[7149:60b] add: 3887034591
2014-03-05 13:14:29.233 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:29.237 app[7149:60b] add: 48397485
2014-03-05 13:14:29.384 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:29.391 app[7149:60b] add: 3076241399
2014-03-05 13:14:29.555 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:29.561 app[7149:60b] add: 3051826257
2014-03-05 13:14:29.734 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:29.737 app[7149:60b] add: 1916037766
2014-03-05 13:14:29.902 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:29.904 app[7149:60b] add: 3032567003
2014-03-05 13:14:30.081 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:30.083 app[7149:60b] add: 1464536901
2014-03-05 13:14:30.248 app[7149:60b] op1=0
2014-03-05 13:14:30.250 app[7149:60b] add: 1647541451
2014-03-05 13:14:30.417 app[7149:60b] op1=1
2014-03-05 13:14:30.432 app[7149:60b] add: 1647541451
2014-03-05 13:14:30.661 app[7149:60b] op1=0
```

Now, as you can notice, a lot of objects are added to the queue. I can't understand why operation count is so low - after adding 5 operations it should be 5..? I understand it may happen in different thread, but as you can see it is never high enough to cover all these added operations.

As far as i understand, count should show all operations added to the queue not only working one.

I assume my understanding what's happening is near to zero, any help would be welcome.

Comment: BTW: `queue.operations.count` gives exactly the same number as `queue.operationCount`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `AFNetworking`, but I have seen same thing with NSURLConnection.
My idea was to observ `queue.operationCount` to show network activity indicator if it's not null. But I was making async request, and how it was: first performt sending request operation then no operations in queue, because we are waiting response asyncroniously, then device reseived response and in queue appeared downloading response operation, then in queue appeared operation that perform response block handler.